# How to block IPs by generating range?

Tags: ip

I have a lot of DDOS attacks lately and given only the attackers IP.

I want to block them via IPtables. Every time the range of IPs is the same but the actual IPs are different.

How can I create the proper range of IPs so I can block them via firewall while I do not know the netmask?

Comment: These days there are very clever attacks spread over entire ranges of IP addresses. What I do is: Lookup the source country for the IP, then lookup the overall subnet, then block that whole sub-net, as per Maythux's answer below. I do not care about collateral damage. More recently, I don't even bother looking up the country, I just go directly to the China or Hong Kong list. There are many sources, I use: http://freegeoip.net/ and http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the range of addresses is 192.168.1.*

To block is 192.168.1.* addresses:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s is 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

To block is 192.168.*.* addresses:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

To block 192.*.*.* addresses:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

But you have to notice this will also block legitimate traffic from the same range

Comment: thank you ! now i understand a bit better the concept of sub netting

Answer (score 0):

You can also automate for unknown ip ranges, it by setting limits:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
```

- -m limit: This uses the limit iptables extension
- –limit 50/minute: This limits only maximum of 50 connection per minute.
- –limit-burst 200: This value indicates that the limit/minute will be
  enforced only after the total number of connection have reached the
  limit-burst level.

[linux command to prevent dos attack by using netstat and iptables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437059/linux-command-to-prevent-dos-attack-by-using-netstat-and-iptables)

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/prevent-dos-with-iptables/

Comment: could you please explain the rule for me please ? i'm new to all this and not sure i follow you.

if i run a vpn protocol for my office won't this affect the connection for my colleagues ?

Comment: edited:  please double check the info. As far as i understand, only if more than 200 connections are established, the 50/min limit will get enforced.

Comment: basically the rule says you can have 50 incoming connection per minute. all other will be dropped ? what does limit burst does then ?

Comment: if you have more than 200 connections (limit-burst) then ... the ip's that try to connect more than 50 times per minute will be dropped

Comment: i re-read your description again, now all clear. thank you , you've been very helpful !

Comment: you're welcome.  look at the bodhizazen.net  for some DOS simulation with ab to test your settings.  I just wanted to let you know something like this exist. Google around (iptables ddos prevention) and you'll find more of those settings.